# Fast startup for JAX-RS applications during test and development

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, jax-rs

What is the fastest way to start a JAX-RS application? I want to run JAX-RS applications in unittests and restart them repitetively during development to test changes in a browser, so startup time is very important. Servlet specific JAX-RS parts are not needed. JDK HttpServer, Jetty, Tomcat, Grizzly, Netty ... which one starts a JAX-RS application the fastest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My measuring were not exactly scientific, but I found that Grizzly starts pretty fast and even faster than the light weight JDK HTTP server (Grizzly starts about 20% faster). The Grizzly start-up time for a simple JAX-RS application is about 1 second on my not up to date machine.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for anything else, but TomCat is pretty quick.  If I make a change to a java or xsl file, it will reload the server to reflect the updated files.  Javascript changes happened as soon as I refresh (due to it being treated as static content, which I have a servlet filter for).  Even if you need to manually stop the server, clean it, and restart it, at most I'm looking at 10-15 seconds.

Also, this is using Jersey.